# Javascript: Replace needle in haystack that is not between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to replace a needle in a haystack that is not between two characters.

So say I have a regular expression that is `/\bneedle\b/g`, that will match all needle's that are not next to any word character. I want to expand on this and include needle's that are not next to any word character, and NOT between two characters such as [ and ]

So the first three needles will match but the rest will not: `needle: needle's needle [needle] [needle something] needle1 needler`

Any idea how I'd go about doing this?

Comment: So are you trying to isolate just the literal word `needle` or are your examples the specific cases that you want to omit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(^|[^\w\[])(needle)(?![\w\]])/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2bY1/2)

**Breakup:**

```
(^|[^\w\[])    # line start OR a non-word non-[ character
(needle)       # match and group our targeted text
(?![\w\]])     # negative lookahead to fail the match if next char is word char or [
```

---

As per comments below you can use following `replace` code:

```
var str = "needle: needle's needle [needle] [needle something] needle1 needler";
var reg = new RegExp("(^|[^\\w\\[])(needle)(?![\\w\\]])", "gi");
str = str.replace(reg, "$1*$2*");

//=> *needle*: *needle*'s *needle* [needle] [needle something] needle1 needler
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very useful.

Comment: Almost. The matches seem to start with a space (which makes no sense to me as the first capturing group doesn't have a space).

`var reg = new RegExp("(?:^|[^\\w\\[])(needle)(?![\\w\\]])", "gi"); var str = "needle: needle's needle [needle] [needle something] needle1 needler"; str = str.replace(reg, "*$1*");`

Result is `*needle*:*needle*'s*needle* [needle] [needle something] needle1 needler` as you can see, some of the spaces were removed which isn't desired.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to put captured value in `(^|[^\\w\\[])` back in replacement.

Comment: Appears to do what I need, yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: One extra case, but I have a feeling it won't be possible entirely in regex.  I did say that it shouldn't match between two characters so that would include this case: `[something needle else]` with the current regex, the needle matches despite being between [ and ]. I think in such a situation, a negative lookbehind would be useful but unfortunately not currently supported in JavaScript.

Comment: You can try: `/(?:^|[^\w\[])(needle)(?!\w|[^\[\]]*\])/` in that case

Comment: After removing the `?:` from the first group, it seems to work with all the cases I can think of. Can you explain what is happening on the last group?

Comment: As I wrote in answer group#1 has a **line start OR a non-word, non-[ character**